# SQL Identify records which occur more than once in the same year

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a records from which a set of Procedure codes should only occur once per year per member. I'm trying to identify occurrences where this rule is broken.
I've tried the below SQL, is that correct?

**Table**

```
+---------------+--------+-------------+
| ProcedureCode | Member | ServiceDate |
+---------------+--------+-------------+
| G0443         | 1234   | 01-03-2017  |
+---------------+--------+-------------+
| G0443         | 1234   | 05-03-2018  |
+---------------+--------+-------------+
| G0443         | 1234   | 07-03-2018  |
+---------------+--------+-------------+
| G0444         | 3453   | 01-03-2017  |
+---------------+--------+-------------+
| G0443         | 5676   | 07-03-2018  |
+---------------+--------+-------------+
```

Expected results where rule is broken

```
+---------------+--------+
| ProcedureCode | Member |
+---------------+--------+
| G0443         | 1234   |
+---------------+--------+
```

**SQL**

```
Select ProcedureCD, Mbr_Id
From CLAIMS
Where ProcedureCD IN ('G0443', 'G0444')
GROUP BY ProcedureCD,Mbr_Id, YEAR(ServiceFromDate)
having count(YEAR(ServiceFromDate))>1
```

Comment: You tried that and what was the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you've written will work (if you correct the column names- your query uses different column names to the sample data you posted). It can be simplified visually by using `COUNT(*)` in the `HAVING` clause. COUNT works on any non null value and accumulates a 1 for non nulls, or 0 for nulls, but there isn't any significance to using YEAR inside the count in this case because all the dates are non null and count isn't interested in the value - `count(*), count(1), count(0), count(member)`would all work equally here

The only time `count(column)` works differently to `count(*)` is when `column` contains null values. There is also an option of COUNT where you put `DISTINCT` inside the brackets, and this causes the counting to ignore repeated values.

COUNT DISTINCT on a table column that contains 6 rows of values `1, 1, 2, null, 3, 3` would return 3 (3 unique values). COUNTing the same column would return 5 (5 non null values), COUNT(*) would return 6

You should understand that by putting the YEAR(...) in the group by but not the select, you might produce duplicate-looking rows in the output. For example if you had these rows also:

```
 Member, Code, Date
1234, G0443, 1-1-19
1234, G0443, 2-1-19
```

And you're grouping on year (but not showing it) then you'll see:

```
1234, G0443    --it's for year 2018
1234, G0443    --it's for year 2019
```

Personally I think it'd be handy to show the year in the select list, so you can better pinpoint where the problem is, but if you want to squish these duplicate rows, do a SELECT DISTINCT   Alternatively, leverage the difference between count and count distinct: remove the year from the GROUP BY and instead say `HAVING COUNT(*) > COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(ServiceDate))`

As discussed above a count(*) will be greater than a count distinct year if there are duplicated years

Answer (score 1):

```
Select ProcedureCode, Member,YEAR(ServiceDate) [Year],Count(*) Occurences
From CLAIMS 
Where ProcedureCode IN ('G0443', 'G0444')
GROUP BY ProcedureCode, Member,YEAR(ServiceDate)
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

Comment: While code-only answers work in that they solve a problem, they don't necessarily teach the OP anything. Please consider adding some extra explanatory notes so the OP can benefit from your knowledge rather than just having answers handed to them

Answer (score 1):

Hope This code will help you

```
create table  #temp (ProcedureCode varchar(20),Member varchar(20),ServiceDate Date)
insert into #temp (ProcedureCode,Member,ServiceDate) values ('G0443','1234','01-03-2017')
insert into #temp (ProcedureCode,Member,ServiceDate) values ('G0443','1234','05-03-2018 ')
insert into #temp (ProcedureCode,Member,ServiceDate) values ('G0443','1234','07-03-2018')
insert into #temp (ProcedureCode,Member,ServiceDate) values ('G0444','3453','01-03-2017')
insert into #temp (ProcedureCode,Member,ServiceDate) values ('G0443','5676','07-03-2018')

select ProcedureCode,Member from #temp
where YEAR(ServiceDate) in (Select year(ServiceDate) ServiceDate from #temp group by 
ServiceDate having count(ServiceDate)>1)
and Member in (Select Member from #temp group by Member having count(Member)>1)
Group by ProcedureCode,Member 

 drop table #temp
```

[image]